# How to Remove element of a List if a file exists VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How do i remove an element or item in a `List(Of String)` if that same element exists as a file? i have this code but it doesn't work, it doesn't remove anything.

`dest` is sometimes like this `D:\Test`

```
Dim dest As String = Label1.Text

For i = 0 to myfiles.Count - 1
   If File.Exists(Path.Combine(dest, myfiles(i))) Then
       myfiles.Remove(myfiles(i))
   End If
Next
```

I'm using a `FileSystemWatcher` to add the files in a `List(Of String)`.

```
Sub FileLogs()
    watchfolder = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()

    Dim src As String = Label5.Text

    watchfolder.Path = src
    watchfolder.IncludeSubdirectories = True

    watchfolder.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
    watchfolder.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName Or IO.NotifyFilters.FileName
    watchfolder.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Size Or IO.NotifyFilters.Size

    AddHandler watchfolder.Changed, AddressOf logattrichanged

    'Start watching for renames of folders and files
    watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub logattrichanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    Dim lastWriteTime As DateTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(e.FullPath)
    If lastWriteTime <> lastRead Then
            myfiles.Add(e.Name)
        lastRead = lastWriteTime
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Dump all the files that need removed to a new list. When done loop through them and remove them from your other list. You are trying to remove an item while looping through it, you may throw an error while doing so. For example you are changing the index if you remove an item...

Comment: Are you certain that the `File.Exists` check is returning `True`? You're also modifying a collection while you're iterating over it, which is bad form (and I think would cause a runtime error). You can workaround that by iterating over the list backwards, or as Codexer says, add the `mifiles(i)` entry to a new temporary list. Once populated, use that temp list to mutate the `myfiles` list.

Comment: No it's not correct please see what I mention and what @Cᴏʀʏ said...

Comment: Awesome he removed comment, no I'm not talking to myself...

Comment: I'm sorry i was about to edit my comment when i saw CORY's updated comment. Like what I was asking, Is my code correct?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what `dest` is, and show how `myfiles` is built and an example of what it contains? It's impossible to debug your code since it's not a [mcve]. Please review the [ask] portion of the [help]. Without providing more details, this question is likely to get closed.

Comment: In your edit, you're listener for change events is `logattrichanged`, yet you provided the definition for `logcreated` only. My guess now is that `myfiles` is actually empty. Is that a typo, or, could you please provide the definition of `logattrichanged`?

Comment: My Bad. Im so sorry.

Comment: Next question: have you debugged this code? Put some breakpoints on the first line of the `logattrichanged` event, and launch or attach a debugger to your running process. Does the breakpoint get hit? Does anything get added to `myfiles`? Are the events firing? If you inspect the values as you debug, does anything not match what you would expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `dest` is a valid path, and that `myfiles` is a collection of valid filenames, here's how I would approach this:

```
Dim dest As String = Label1.Text

' Before we do anything at all, make sure dest is actually a path
If Not Directory.Exists(dest) Then
    Throw New DirectoryNotFoundException("dest is not valid.")
End If

' Set up a temporary list of items to remove, no larger than the original list
Dim toRemove As New List(Of String)(myfiles.Count)

' Loop over myfiles and add to the delete queue anything that actually exists
For Each myfile in myfiles
    If File.Exists(Path.Combine(dest, myfile)) Then
        toRemove.Add(myFile)
    End If
Next

' If there's anything in the removal queue, try to remove it from the original list
For Each removal in toRemove
    myfiles.Remove(removal)
Next
```

Now you could shorten this up a lot using some LINQ, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.